# Travis CI Jest Preset react-native not found

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, travis-ci, jestjs

I'm having a react-native app.

Today I added unit tests with Jest and I hooked up Travis CI. When I run the tests locally, everything is fine. but when they run in Travis, I get this error:

`Validation Error: Preset react-native not found.`

Thanks.

Comment: Check your package.json to see if jest-react-native is in there. If not do npm install –save jest-react-native.

Comment: It is not. But I think Facebook said it is included in the latest version. I started my app few days ago

Comment: You are right. I don’t think it is needed any more. I’m not sure now. Check for babel-jest and Babel-preset-react-native as well then. Maybe something that is in your local node modules but is not saved to package.json

Comment: Everything is included and it is still not working

Comment: Okay, could you provide a minimum setup to reproduce the error? I’m down to try it out.

Comment: I had two folders with one repo, and a travis config using matrix. I solved it by moving the two folders into separate repos

Comment: this can happen if your `rootDir` is incorrectly set

Answer (score 6):

I had this issue and even tried it in a fresh project.

[image]

I fixed it by removing

```
"jest": {
    "preset": "react-native"
}
```

from my package.json.

Doing this enabled me to run `npm run test` or `jest` to run **jest**.

My guess (i could be wrong) is newer versions of jest wont need that config in the packages.json file anymore.

Answer (score 2):

In my case, it happened because I was working on a module (library) that only had `'react-native'` as in `peerDependencies`. Adding `'react-native'` to `"devDepenencies"` fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue solved by updating jest, jest-ci package.

Why we have this issue?

I compared `react-native` from version `0.57.0` to `0.59.3` and found that `react-native` replaced `jest-preset.json` with `jest-preset.js`, but `jest` older versions only support `jest-preset.json`.

So all we need to do is to upgrade `jest` and `jest-cli` to the latest version where it support both `.js` and `.json`

You can check 'node_modules/jest-config/build/normalize.js' if you can find

```js
const PRESET_EXTENSIONS = ['.json', '.js'];
```

you are at the correct version.

Answer (score 0):

Doing npm i or yarn install fixed the issue for me.